# Replace String via Java Spring Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I need to replace or remove some chars from user input

Is is possible declare annotation for change value after set?

for example, I have UserDTO class with username field. I want to change Unicode characters.

Please note that I using Spring Data + Web Service

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public RestResult register(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
  ...
}
```

Comment: You would want to use a custom deserializer for the UserDTO.

Comment: Check this: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: @Shadov thx, it possible but less handle on classes. I want to do this for some class using annotation for field or class level

Comment: If you're using Jackson. You may be able to add some clever logic into `@JsonCreator` to handle your logic when passed into the constructor

Comment: @shinjw thx, may be this is answer. i will check

Comment: you put your json annotations on getter and not attributes, And manipulate as you want. in your getter method replace all unncessary chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches for this.

You can write the setter for the username object to handle this logic. The caveat of this is any username value passed through your setter will go through your String massaging.

```
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username.replace("A", "B");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

Another possible way of doing this is by using the `@JsonCreator` annotation provided by [`Jackson`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html).

You'll need to keep in mind that this will become the deserialization strategy across all objects using the `UserDTO` object. But considering that you are looking to swap out unicode(most likely to an internal readable format) I would imagine that this would fit your use case.

```
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private String username;

    @JsonCreator
    public UserDTO(@JsonProperty("username") String username) {
        this.username = username.replace("A", "B");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

So when passed through into your method, "ABC" will resolve to "BBC". This may be the preferred approach in your case, since it would give you the flexibility to adjust the object when needed without going through your username String cleaning. Objects created by serialization and constructor will go through the cleaning, but the setter will take the value as is. It's easy to get bit by logic in getters and setters.

Comment: thanks a lot for complete answer. but Is it possible to write custom annotation for class or field???

Comment: Are you talking about an additional behavior that the annotated field method or class would perform?

Comment: not for now. i think even jackson custom deserializer is  good solution for me. any how i like annotation that spring and hibernate using them